# Determine if external HWND using DirectX/OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, directx, gdi

Is there any way to tell if an external HWND is using DirectX/OpenGL?

I've been using GetWindowDC along wit BitBlt to do windows capture.  But I realized that things like VLC, Youtube, and other graphics card accelerated windows aren't capturable.  If I had a reliable way of knowing if the window was capturable then I could treat windows differently.

Comment: If you can get a HDC, you could try calling `GetPixelFormat(hdc)`. I don't know if that will give you the pixel format if you call it from another process, even you have the right window. The OpenGL window is of course not normally the top level window of the app.

Comment: Another somewhat far fetched idea: There's probably a way to enumerate what libraries an app has loaded. If you can figure out how to do that, you might be able to check if a given app loaded DirectX/OpenGL libraries.

Comment: Reto.  Something like PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL?  What fields would help me identify OpenGL?  I'll try to query it and see what I get.